# Why is it that setting a value on a dataframe that is (I think) a copy changing the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I create a dataframe and (I think) I create a copy out of it. I think I create a copy out of it since `._is_view` property is `False`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':['x','y','z']})

df.loc[[True, True, False],'a']._is_view
output: False
```

So setting this copy equal to some value should not change the original dataframe, right?

However, the following changes the original dataframe

```
df.loc[[True, True, False],'a'] = 'abcd'
print(df)
output:
      a  b
0  abcd  x
1  abcd  y
2     3  z
```

Can you please help me understand this behavior by pandas?

Answer (score 2):

This is a fully expected behavior.

If you were doing (= **getting** a slice):

```
df2 = df.loc[[True, True, False],'a']

df2.loc[:,'a'] = 'abcd'
```

You would be modifying `df2` and leaving `df1` unchanged.

However by doing (**setting** the data):

```
df.loc[[True, True, False],'a'] = 'abcd'
```

You perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), which does modify the data in place.

Comment: I guess I am going back to the first square of Python and it is unnerving. However, can you please explain why is that so? ```df2 = df.loc[[True, True, False],'a']``` would just assign a name ```df2``` to whatever ```df.loc[[True, True, False],'a']``` represents, right? How is Python making the distinction between the two?

Comment: nevermind, it got answered by juanpa. Thank you for the answer. It helped me. Upvoted

Comment: @figs_and_nuts no, in this case pandas explicitly makes a copy since you used `loc`. This isn't always the case and can lead to [`SettingWithCopyWarning`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) (somethimes with slicing with `[…]` instead of `loc`)

Answer (score 2):

No, that isn't how that works. This expression:

```
df.loc[[True, True, False],'a']
```

Is essentially evaluated to:

```
df.loc.__getitem__(([True, True, False],'a'))
```

Which happens to return a new `pd.DataFrame` object that isn't a view.

But this statement:

```
df.loc[[True, True, False],'a'] = 'abcd'
```

Is evaluated as:

```
df.loc.__setitem__(([True, True, False],'a'), 'abcd')
```

which modifies the underlying dataframe. Nowhere in the above expression does a new dataframe object get created, view or otherwise. The fact that the index is the same isn't really relevant. These two methods, `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` are doing two different things. `__setitem__` **always** mutates. `__getitem__` returns a new `pd.DataFrame` object, always, but that object may be a view of the original data.

Consider just a list:

```
data = [1,2,3,4]
data2 = data[:2]
```

is a copy. But:

```
data[:2] = [9, 9]
print(data)
```

still modifies the original list.

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you :)